# Problem with displaying field using Views

Tags: views, search, rating

My goal is to use Search API so that I can create a custom search page using Views.  I want to add the "rating" widget (rate module), but there is no way to include it in the Search API fields. Thus, I tried to fix it by adding custom field to Search API index.

```
function rate_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
  $info['node']['properties']['widget'] = array(
    'label' => t('Rating widget'),
    'description' => t('Rating widget'),
    'getter callback' => 'display_widget',
  );
}
function display_widget($node) {
     print rate_generate_widget('1', 'node', $node->nid);
}
```

However, I am getting AJAX errors

[image]

and problems with displaying widgets.

[image]

Please can someone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a Solr based search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a Solr/ElasticDB search backend under Search API, you could try this approach.

Create a view mode on the node type (ex. Search Result), then create a template with the html markup when rendered for it. Include all the fields in the display and configure the formatters as you want them.

Next, install [Search API View Modes](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_view_modes), and configure that view mode to be indexed. It will render that node before indexing it into a new field (search server side). Then, you can create a view display that shows that field, which is just HTML, and bypass some of these issues.

I use this method in every Search API based search I encounter. You're basically storing the rendered HTML on the search server, then printing that as the result.

I can't tell if you are on Drupal 7 or 8. Note that the 8.x branch 'works' but may have some bugs. I have only been able to test simple setups and not use it on production like the 7.x branch.